# Can't figure out Galaga in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, canvas

For my final project at school I have to build Galaga in WPF, I'm using two canvases that alternate visibility so as to buffer behind the scenes to hide visible lag. I have it so once the player starts the game it runs this method

```
public void gameRunning()
    {

        while (true)
        {
            ProcessEvents();
            UpdateAllEntities();
            Draw();
            Thread.Sleep(1000 / 30);
        }
    }
```

which processes any events, updates the entities of my ship locations, bad guy locations, any collision, etc. Then draws to my second (buffer) canvas and then sleeps so that the game runs at 30fps.

When it enters into the gameRunning() method it freezes. I haven't done anything this complex so I am pretty lost. Here are the two methods my Draw() calls

```
public void DrawAllEntities()
    {
        if (buffer) {
            Canvas2.Children.Clear();
            Canvas2.Children.Add(theShip.getImage());
        }
        else
        {
            Canvas1.Children.Clear();
            Canvas1.Children.Add(theShip.getImage());
        }
    }

    public void SwapBuffers()
    {
        if (buffer)
        {
            Canvas1.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            Canvas2.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
        }
        else
        {
            Canvas2.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            Canvas1.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
        }
    }
```

I couldn't get DrawAllEntities() to work, I tried it with Canvas.setLeft(), setTop() but it didn't work. Any help or advice would be super appreciated, thanks.

Comment: You are sleeping the UI thread. Don't do that. Use `Task.Delay` or run this on a different thread (*especially* if update does complex logic)

Comment: WPF is already double buffered and hardware accelerated. You don't need to flip canvases. You shouldn't add remove the ship, just apply an animation to animate the position, or set the position manually. As brad mentioned, no sleeps... using a timer.

Comment: One other tip, *strongly* consider using TranslateTransform instead of Canvas. Its far more performant